# SyntaxError: Unexpected token (244:78) - Nodejs, Express, jade, mysql

Tags: node.js, express.js, jade

Estou desenvolvendo um programa e do nada na criação de uma página simples apareceu o erro abaixo:

O programa está funcionando tudo, menos essa página que aparece esse erro:

Já repassei todas as linhas e não encontrei nada, porque não alterei nada, entende!

Ao procurar sobre o erro, a maioria diz que esta relacionado ao react e ao babel-loader, só que eu não uso isso. A não ser que esse babel-loader seja algum mecanismo interno.

Já reinstalei o meu node_modules e não adiantou.

Estou usando Ubuntu-Server 16, Nodejs v4.2.6, Express v4.14.0, jade, mysql v5.5,

Desde já agradeço,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (244:78)
at Parser.pp.raise (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:943:13)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1503:8)
at Parser.pp.expect (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1497:26)
at Parser.pp.parseParenExpression (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:342:8)
at Parser.pp.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:399:16)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:297:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:216:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:197:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:151:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:133:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:110:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprList (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:651:185)
at Parser.pp.parseSubscripts (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:240:29)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:219:15)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:197:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:151:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:133:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/var/www/html/nodejs/paif/descoberto/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:110:19)
```

controller.js

```
getSocial: function(req,res){
        var _id = req.params.id;

        db.query(
            'SELECT * FROM social WHERE idCliente = ?', _id, function(err, result){
                if(err) throw err;

                res.render('pesquisaSocial');
        });
    },
}

return controller;}
```

rotas.js

```
module.exports = function(app){

var ctl = app.controllers.controllers;

app.route('/')
    .get(ctl.login)

app.route('/principal')
    .get(ctl.lista);

app.route('/cadastro')
    .get(ctl.getCad)
    .post(ctl.postCad);

app.route('/show/:id')
    .get(ctl.getRegistroShowCad)
    .post(ctl.postRegistro);

app.route('/titular/:id')
    .get(ctl.getUpdate)
    .post(ctl.updateCad);

app.route('/delete')
    .post(ctl.deleteCad);

app.route('/despesas/:id')
    .get(ctl.getDespesa)
    .post(ctl.postDespesa);

app.route('/membros/:id')
    .get(ctl.getMembros)
    .post(ctl.postMembros);

app.route('/membros/show/:id/:id2')
    .get(ctl.showMembros)
    .post(ctl.updateMembros);

app.route('/delete/membros')
    .post(ctl.deleteMembros);

app.route('/pesquisa/social/:id')
    .get(ctl.getSocial);}
```

pesquisaSocial.jade

```
extends layout

block content
br
p.text-center PESQUISA SOCIAL

div.container
    hr
    form(method='POST' action='#')

        label(for='perguntaSocial_1') 1 - De que forma a família (ou membro da família) acessou a unidade para o primeiro atendimento?
        select.form-control(name='perguntaSocial_1')

            option(value='Escolha uma opcao' selected disabled hidden) #{data[0].perguntaSocial_1 || Escolha uma opção}
            option(value='Por demanda espontanea')
                |Por demanda espontanea
            option(value='Em decorrencia de Busca Ativa realizada pela equipe da unidade')
                |Em decorrencia de Busca Ativa realizada pela equipe da unidade
            option(value='Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado por outros serviços/unidades da Proteção Social Basica')
                |Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado por outros serviços/unidades da Proteção Social Basica
            option(value='Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado por outros serviços/unidades da Protecao Social Especial')
                |Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado por outros serviços/unidades da Protecao Social Especial
            option(value='Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pela área de Saúde')
                |Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pela área de Saúde
            option(value='Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pela área da Educacao')
                |Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pela área da Educacao
            option(value='Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado por outras Políticas Setorias')
                |Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado por outras Políticas Setorias
            option(value='Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pelo Conselho Tutelar')
                |Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pelo Conselho Tutelar
            option(value='Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pelo Poder Judiciario')
                |Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pelo Poder Judiciario
            option(value='Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pelo Sistema de Garantia de Direitos (Defensoria Publica, Ministério Público,  Delegacias)')
                |Em decorrencia de encaminhamento realizado pelo Sistema de Garantia de Direitos (Defensoria Publica, Ministério Público, Delegacias)
            option(value='Outros encaminhamentos')
                |Outros encaminhamentos

        br
        label(for='perguntaSocial_2') 2 - Sempre que o acesso for decorrente de algum encaminhamento, identifique detalhadamente o NOME e CONTATO do órgão/unidade que encaminhou o usuário:
        input.form-control(type='text' name='perguntaSocial_2' value='#{data[0].perguntaSocial_2}')

        br
        label(for='perguntaSocial_3') 3 - Quais as razões, demandas ou necessidades que motivaram este primeiro atendimento?
        input.form-control(type='text' name='perguntaSocial_3' value='#{data[0].perguntaSocial_3}')
```

Comment: Não acho que esse erro seja do babel ou outro loader. Consegues tirar coisas do jade até a página funcionar? Já agora devias usar o node v6 e mudar para Pug uma vez que o Jade foi descontinuado.

Comment: O jade deve esta identificando " (ou membro da família) " como um token.

Comment: Srs. Queria agradecer a ajuda primeiramente. @Paulo, realmente tinha alguma coisa que o jade estava detectando e eu não. Eu refiz a página e ela voltou a funcionar, mas ainda sim, não identifiquei o que estava de errado. Eu apenas tirei os values.